# Options to override/reconfigure ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.DataContractDeserializer

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, servicestack

We are currently re-writing a legacy system and have been using ServiceStack for a multitude of reasons. We work with resumes/pd's etc. so we have to deal with larger messages. While testing one of our service messages, we got this error message: `The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.`

Some research led me to the `ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.DataContractDeserializer` where in the call to `Instance()` the `MaxStringContentLength` is set to 1024*1024 or 1048576 (bytes I believe). Without having to recompile the class, is there an alternative way to increase the `MaxStringContentLength` which is set in the call to `Instance()` (e.g. Plugin/Feature, etc.)? Lastly, although we would prefer to stream this data there are outside factors preventing us from doing so at the moment.

Comment: It seems to be possible to set the value of Instance: `DataContractDeserializer.Instance = new DataContractDeserializer(new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas { ... })`. But, when I tried to do this in my AppHost init code, it didn't seem to make any difference with the XML deserialization behavior.

Comment: This question seems to be realated: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/4z6ckmKOSRo/htGHY7lorBcJ